# Masking a donut shape in a UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, cashapelayer

I am trying to cut a donut shape into a UIImageView. I can currently only achieve a circle cutout like so:

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics

class AvatarImageView: UIImageView {

    enum AvatarImageViewOnlineStatus {
        case online
        case offline
        case hidden
    }

    var rounded: Bool = false
    var onlineStatus: AvatarImageViewOnlineStatus = .hidden

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        guard !rounded else { return }
        if let image = image, !rounded {
            self.image = image.af_imageRoundedIntoCircle()
            rounded = true
        }

        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)
        let maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = rect

        let mainPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
        let circlePath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 30, height: 30))
        mainPath.append(circlePath)

        maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
        maskLayer.path = mainPath.cgPath
        maskLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        maskLayer.lineWidth = 10.0
        layer.mask = maskLayer
    }

}
```

[image]

Is it possible to create a donut shaped cutout using masks?

Comment: What result are you expecting and how is that different from the result you're getting? The result looks like a donut with a slightly offset hole to me.

Comment: A donut shape cut into the circular profile image

Comment: Can you draw an example of what that would look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took a little more effort then I was expecting and the solution wasn't obvious ... until I found it, then it was like, oh, yeah, sure :/

The "basic" idea is, you want to "cut out" a section of the an existing path, the solution wasn't obvious, because `UIBezierPath` doesn't provide a "subtract" or "remove" method.  Instead, you need to "reverse" the path, for example...

```
let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
path.append(UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)).reversing())
path.append(UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 75, y: 75, width: 50, height: 50)))
```

And, because "out-of-context" snippets are rarely helpful, this is the playground I used to test it (supply own image)...

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics

let image = UIImage(named: "Profile")
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
let backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
backgroundView.addSubview(imageView)

imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.image = image
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 100

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
path.append(UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)).reversing())
path.append(UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 75, y: 75, width: 50, height: 50)))

shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
shapeLayer.frame = imageView.bounds

imageView.layer.mask = shapeLayer
backgroundView
```

And my results...

[image: Those are the droids you're looking for]

The green color is from the `backgroundView` on which the `UIImageView` resides

Now, if you would prefer something more like...

[image: I can't see anything out of this helmet]

Then just get rid of the second `append` statement, `path.append(UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 75, y: 75, width: 50, height: 50)))`

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I wanted! Thanks so much